# How to pass value to master pages user control

Tags: vb.net, controls, master-pages

I have problem. I have site.master which includes a couple of user controls. Now I need to pass value (string) from actual pages code behind to master pages user control (Property) .

**So my master is like this:**

```
<%@ Master Language="VB" CodeFile="/scripts/pohjakoodit.master.vb" Inherits="pohjakoodit"  AutoEventWireup="false"  debug="false" %>
```

... on the end of master there is:

```
<ucSheriff:sheriffala ID="sheriffala" statvalue="atesti" runat="server" />
```

**Then I have actual page which starts like this:**

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" MasterPageFile="site.master" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="/scripts/alkuuutisetxw.aspx.vb" Inherits="uutiset_index" debug="true"  %>
```

**The sheriffala.ascx has property**

```
dim Public staref As String = ""    

    Public Property statvalue() As String
        Get
            Return statvalue
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            staref = value
        End Set
    End Property
```

Now I try to access property statvalue from user control sheriffala in code behind file alkuuutisetxw.aspx.vb.

I have tried the very basics like 
`sheriffala.statvalue = "my srting"`
or
`page.master.sheriffala.statvalue = "my srting"`
And tried couple of binding, non of them have't worked out.

So how do I pass a string to user controls property from code behind file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure your UserControl is Public on your MasterPage. Then in the CodeBehind of your ContentPage, you need to create an instance of your MasterPage and you should be good to go to access `statvalue()`, since it's already Public.

Or if you don't like messing with the designer file, you can make properties that expose your UserControls and MasterPage:

### MasterPage:

```
Public ReadOnly Property UCSheriffala() As Sheriffala
    Get
        Return Me.Sheriffala
    End Get
End Property
```

### Content Page:

```
Public Shadows ReadOnly Property Master() As Pohjakoodit
    Get
        Return CType(MyBase.Master, Pohjakoodit)
    End Get
End Property
```

### Usage Example:

```
Response.Write(Master.UCSheriffala.statvalue)
```

Comment: I tryed that and stoped on your master code with error  BC30002: Type 'Sherrifala' is not defined.

Comment: @Timo77 - It's probably b/c it needed to be Sheriffala to match the ID of your UserControl.  I simply mistyped it.